# How do parentheses work with colons?

Tags: punctuation

So I am writing an essay analyzing the poem "Red Beans and Rice" by Elton Glaser, but I have run into a little problem. In my opening paragraph, I have the phrase

> I thought up a nice phrase that I use to describe this poem (and through proxy, New Orleans)

But, I am not quite sure where to place a colon—after the parentheses

> I thought up a nice phrase that I use to describe this poem (and through proxy, New Orleans): Chaotic neutral every day except for Sunday.

Or before the parentheses.

> I thought up a nice phrase that I use to describe this poem: (and through proxy, New Orleans.) Chaotic neutral every day except for Sunday.

I don't really want to use an em dash, as I used one in the line directly above in order to slap a fragment onto the end of a sentence. This is supposed to be MLA formatted, if that matters. After the parentheses feels right to me but both placements just look weird to me.

I am, however, considering just cutting out the DnD reference out of it, as it would require explaining, and that would probably make my essay that much less about poetic analysis and just as much more about Dungeons and Dragons.

Comment: after the colon we are starting a new statement - your parenthesis belongs to the first statement, so 1 is correct

Comment: Two ideas: Leave out the opening remarks about your opinion, as we know who thought up the idea, you did; and throw in a phrase before the colon. Thus, "A phrase that describes this poem (and through proxy, New Orleans) **is just this**: Chaotic neutral every day except for Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than parentheses, you could use parenthetic commas. Then the colon would include the second comma of the pair, like this:

> > I thought up a nice phrase that I use to describe this poem, and through proxy, New Orleans: Chaotic neutral every day except for Sunday.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to place a comma after the closing parenthesis:

> I thought up a nice phrase that I use to describe this poem (and through proxy, New Orleans), Chaotic neutral every day except for Sunday.

Also note that the comma would be necessary even if the parentheses were removed, because it joins a dependent and independent clause:

> I thought up a nice phrase that I use to describe this poem, Chaotic neutral every day except for Sunday.

Comment: So I can't use a colon to join the two clauses? It just looks weird to me no matter how I write it.

Comment: You can use colon to join two clauses but in this context somehow comma feels more appropriate to me.

Comment: A comma is absolutely not appropriate here. A colon is the punctuation to use.